# Stop execution of a page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have a task board, some person is working on some task, if task is assigned to another person by his manager the first person who is working on the task board, his execution should be stopped, and a message should be displayed that "This task is assigned to some one else."

I tried using following in page load.

```cs
//Code Behind
if (!Owner)
{
    SomecontrolsToHide();
    MessageDisplay();    // JavaScript function call using RegisterStartupScript()
    Response.End();    
}

protected void MessageDisplay()
{
    string dbMessage = "Task is assigned to someone else.";
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ShowMessageWrapup_" + UniqueID, "showMessageDisplay('','" + dbMessage + "');", true);   
}
```

```js
// JavaScript function that displays message.
function showMessageDisplay(args, displayMessage) {
    if (displayMessage != "") {                        
        document.getElementById("spanMessage").innerHTML = displayMessage;
        document.getElementById("spanMessage").style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

It stops the execution but message is not displayed and Controls are not hidden too.

What should I do?

Comment: Please post the code inside MessageDisplay()

Comment: Stopping the execution means that nothing will be sent to the browser after `Response.End()`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: perhaps a `redirect` or `server.transfer` would be better here?

Comment: @Oded, I have multiple events on the page with which post back is performed, for example user clicked a button then i want to display message using the above javascript code, and return without executing the click event.

Comment: @Eonasdan, I want to remain on the same page. and display message in a div using javascript.

Comment: why don't you hide the buttons / links instead of blocking the action?

Answer (score 4):

Don't do Response.End(). Just return without doing anything.

Comment: how, as i have different events on the page. for example user clicked a button, then how can i return without executing button's click event.

Comment: That's where you should put if (!Owner).

Comment: you mean like 
if(!Owner)
{
  return;
}

Comment: return will just return from page_load event but button's click event will still fire.

Comment: if you do sth on button click that's where you should do what should be done - in btn click handler. Not in page_load. In click handler you check if (!Ownher) and hide controls and return.

Comment: I have multiple events on page, then I need to check (!Owner) condition in every event. I want to avoid that, so I want to do that in page_load.

Comment: You should put logic in one place.

Answer (score 0):

This will show the message box. Try this.

```
Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('You are not allowed for this task !!!')</script>");
```